# What is the Relation between "Ether" and "ETH"? (or: What to do with farmed "ether"?)

Tags: mining, ether, solo-mining

Over the weekend i let my gaming PC running with "ethminer" all the time using my GPU.

When i checked my ballance on sunday evening using geth it showed me "85 ether":

```
$ geth attach
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether")
> 85
```

Some hours later it was increasing until 105. But in public explorer (https://etherscan.io) it was already 0 ETH.

What can i do with this "ether"? I guess it has nothing to do with ETH as the ethereum currency as i would be rich then in upcoming days.

How is the relation between "ether" and "ETH"?

*Update:*

Today the balance turned down to Zero (i did nothing).

Comment: Hi there. Which network are you mining on? The public main net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ether is a denomination of currency, like dollars and cents. ETH is a currency (arguably), like US currency and currency of Great Britain. Also, one ETH means one ether in the Ethereum main net like one USD means one dollar in the US currency and one GBP means one pound in the Great Britain currency.

The reason why your balance dropped was because your computer thought it had found new blocks and were adding them to the blockchain. However, it was working from a previous point in time when your GPU would have been (relatively) a lot more powerful so it was able to find a few blocks. As your computer caught up to the state of the network, `geth` realized that the blocks it thought you had found already had solutions in the main net and thus, it agreed, someone else's account should receive the credit for those blocks, not you. As a result, your balance in `geth` dropped.

Answer (score 0):

ethminer is a problem solver, in particular Proof of Work for the Ethereum Network.

`eth.coinbase` is just an address you can set in geth (not necessary yours) and it's the address rewarded for mining a block. If it seems to you *to good to be true*, just check the balance on a [public explorer](https://etherscan.io/)

Ether is the intrinsic coin of the Ethereum Network, and it is what you gain when you mine a block. ETH is just an abbreviation for Ether.

Good luck with your solo mining... ;-)

Comment: On public explorer this address (i created this address with "geth account new") contained always 0$ (also 2 days later). But in my account list it was 105 for some hours (increasing from 0 to 105 in steps of 5). Now it contains 0 even if i did nothing with the wallet. Should it be right that i farmed 105 ETH with one GPU on 2 days? Can't believe it

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do solo mining in Ethereum by now. To obtain 105 ether you should have mined about 20 blocks (5 ether per block + fees), this can't be done with 2 GPU. 0 is the true balance, sorry.

Comment: Anyway, if you are really interested in mining with GPU, search on google for "ethereum mining pool". You can join others in the job, i.e. https://ethermine.org.